# How can i change the color of my name?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have been recently searching for a way to change a player's name color in version 1.12 (above the player, in scoreboards and in chat), and I have found many answers on forums offering to use a `/nick` command, but that is available only when using a mod.

I have heard that this is possible with the `/scoreboard` command, but I haven't figured out how.

**Is there any way to change the color of a player's name in Vanilla Minecraft version 1.12?**

Comment: `minecraft.gamepedia.com/scoreboard`, press Ctrl+F and type "team".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this still works but yes, you're right. Using `/scoreboard teams add {{YOUR TEAM NAME}}` & then `/scoreboard teams option {{YOUR TEAM NAME}} color {{COLOR}}` should turn your name to your chosen color.

If you're having trouble finding exact color names, I've grabbed a quick list of them from the minecraft wiki.

[image: List of colors]

Enjoy!

By the way, the only place you would use `/nick` would be in a server that has the plugin.

Comment: Is there an option to use RGB or other color schemes to further specify the color used, instead of using prefixed color names?

Comment: @user3.14159265359 Not that i know of, but i'm sure there's a mod for it.

Comment: Well, RIP custom name colors on my Realms then... :-)